# IBM worklight for developing static websites

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to Worklight and am currently doing proof of concepts to understand the features and strengths of the platform to create mobile web apps, hybrid apps and native apps.

Can IBM Worklight also be used for developing static information websites for multiple mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if all you want to do is serve dynamic content form your server to the mobile device there are some advantages to use Worklight, for example by wrapping your site in a hybrid shell you can gain the presence in application stores (Apple iTunes and Google Play).

You can check "Module 45.1 – Worklight App as a Container For Server Generated Pages" ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_45_1_-_Worklight_App_as_a_Container_for_Server_Generated_Pages.pdf for more information about how to do it.

If you will not use your static site as the resource of the content but will use the Worklight application you will have a few advantages
1) Will work offline
2) Faster response time (no round trips (HTTP requests) to get the whole HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images)

At the end of the day Worklight application are for applications, where there is a interaction between backends and the client and usage of device capabilities (like location, camera, etc.) and not only static content.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be used to create static sites? Yes. Is that a good use of the software license? Probably not. There is a lot more power in Worklight than just creating a static site. I would suggest really understanding responsive web design and using that to create your mobile friendly sites.